# Put a boolean False inside a runloop while

Tags: ios, ftp, uiactivityindicatorview, chilkat

i'm trying to get directory file listing from my ftp server using Chilkat library. 
In this case, i want to animating a UIActivityIndicatorView when the process is running. But the problem is, the UIActivityIndicatorView never start to animate. The code I use is :

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
[selfgetListFromPath:ftpPath withConnection:ftpConnect];
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

activityIndicator is an object of `UIActivityIndicatorView`, `ftpPath` is a NSString of my file path in FTP server, and `getListFromPath` is the method for getting list from FTP server using Chilkat algorithm, `ftpConnect` is an object of FTP Connection Class.

I was try to use NSRunLoop before called `getListFromPath` function, so I changed my code into :

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

BOOL waitingOnProcessing = YES;
NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
while (waitingOnProcessing && [currentRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) {

}

[self getListFromPath:ftpPath withConnection:ftpConnect];
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

this make the `activityIndicator` animating, but the `getListFromPath` never fired. After a trial, i choosed to changed again my code into :

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    BOOL waitingOnProcessing = YES;
    NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    while (waitingOnProcessing && [currentRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) {
        waitingOnProcessing = NO;       
    }

    [self getListFromPath:ftpPath withConnection:ftpConnect];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

it make the `activityIndicator` animating, and also fired the `getListFromPath` function. But i'm doubt with this code, am i right with this code? or maybe there is a bad practice for using NSRunLoop? 
can somebody tell me

Thank you

Comment: Finally, i have found the answer, this http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/ link help me to find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs as in a "black box" :

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self getListFromPath:ftpPath];
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

So UI updates occur when your method returns, and you won't see the update.

What you need to do is startAnimating your activity indicator, then start your `getListFromPath` in another thread. When that method terminates, you call back your main thread telling it to stopAnimating the indicator.

Use this methods:

```
[NSObject performSelectorInBackground:withObject:]
```

to start your getListFromPath thread, then when it's done, call

```
[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
```

to give the control back to the main thread, which will stop the spinner animation.

Comment: Forgot to tell you: just remember to *always* do UI updates on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i use a performSelectorInBackground:withObject:, it make me have to use @selector(getListFromPath:), right? How about the ftpPath parameter? i cant get the directory file listing without that parameter, can you give me another clue?

Comment: You have to create a `threadedGetListFromPath` method, that will setup an autorelease pool, and start the getListFromPath from inside. Then, call `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(threadedGetListFromPath)]` from your main thread. The `ftpPath` will still be accessible from this method as long as it's a private member (variabe) of the same class. Beware not to modify it as you may run into concurrency problems.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this introduction: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/asynchronous_iphone_nsthread_nstimer

Comment: hmmm...i'm not get it, can you give me an example of threadedGetListFromPath method?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441345/does-uiactivityindicator-require-manual-threading-on-iphone

Comment: i have a problem with that link, if i have 2 parameter for running my function, what i have to do? please see my update for the getListFromPath method

Comment: @Cyrille let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1358/discussion-between-risma-and-cyrille)

Comment: No matter how many parameters you have, as your method is called from threadedGetListFromPath (which takes *no* parameter). All you have to do is make them accessible from anywhere in your class, by declaring them @private in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the Chilkat library, but it must have some way of telling you that you receive an answer from your ftp server. When you got it, you should use a NSNotification or a protocol to tell your view controller that you got an answer. When that happen you stop the spinner.

Comment: I just have the answer from my FTP server, and i have all the list that i want to get, but the problem is, i can't start my activityIndicator to animating. But my last code, make me can do it. The problem is, i just doubt with that code, can i just do that?

Comment: I don't think your last bit of code is the right way of doing it. You need to be sure that you got the answer, only need you stop the the spinner

Comment: using the last code i've made, the spinner is stop after the file listing is showed. Can you tell me another way to do it?

Comment: Tell me one thing, does the Chilkat library provide you some sort of a gotResponseFromServer method?

Comment: Hmm, i think there is a logic like that in Chilkat library

Comment: If there is, you can put a NSNotification inside. Or create a protocol, so the Chilkat library can communicate with your view controller.

Comment: @JackyBoy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1356/discussion-between-risma-and-jacky-boy)